# Derivative of $\sin(x^\circ)$

Tags: derivatives

Plotting the function $f(x)=\sin(x^\circ)$, it might look linear, but after checking it by recreating it as $g(x)=x\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(50^\circ)}{50}\right)\right)$, it is surely not.

What is the derivative of $\sin(x^\circ)$?

Comment: What is $x^o$ here?

Comment: @Cameron I don't quite understand. sin(x°) is a function

Comment: $\sin x = sin x^\circ\frac\pi{180^\circ}$, can you take it from here?

Comment: What's the difficulty you are facing? Do you know what the derivative of $\sin{x}$ is normally? In the normal case, it's assumed that $x$ is in radians. You only need to convert the normal differentiation procedure to degrees and you're basically done.

Comment: @Matt you mean its derivative is cos(x°)? I'm new to math BTW.

Comment: Oh it's degrees. Calculus is not done in degrees because the expressions get unwieldy. Calculus with trig functions is almost universally done in radians.

Comment: Well, almost.
$$
\sin{x^{\circ}} = \sin{\left( x \cdot \frac{\pi}{180} \right)} \quad \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\sin{\left( x \cdot \frac{\pi}{180} \right)}  = \frac{\pi}{180} \cos{\left( x \cdot \frac{\pi}{180} \right)} 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a complete circle, you can see the following- $$\frac {x^o}{360}=\frac {x}{2{\pi}}$$
$$x={{\pi}x^o\over {180}}$$
You can just replace $x^o$ and convert to radians as all trigonometric derivations are done in radians. Hence you can differentiate as usual.
$$\frac {d}{dx}\sin{x^{\circ}} = \frac{d}{dx}\sin{\left( \frac{x\pi}{180} \right)}  = \frac{\pi}{180} \cos{\left(\frac{x\pi}{180} \right)}=\frac{\pi}{180} \cos x^{\circ}$$

Comment: I can now compute its taylor series so that I wouldn't be using scientific calculator anymore (they are expensive), but just an ordinary calculator. Thanks.